# Looping Master or Scene and restoring original position of elements

Tags: gsap

I try to loop a complete header animation endlessly, but I just cannot get it to work:
https://codepen.io/Sixl/pen/jwXGqd

I tried to loop the master like this:

```
var master = new TimelineMax({repeat:-1});
```

Then I tried the same solution on the single scene I'm using:

```
  function sceneOne() {
    var tl = new TimelineMax({repeat:-1});
```

I also tried several solutions with **oncomplete callbacks**.

I finally had some experiments with

```
timeline.seek(0).pause();
timeline.pause(0); //shortcut for the line above
timeline.progress(0).pause();
timeline.totalProgress(0).pause();
timeline.restart(0).pause();
```

inside my scene. Didn't help.

Can somebody point me in the right direction? I cannot find any error in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `entry_heroes` section that is causing the problem as it has itself a `repeat: -1` that means that the section never ends and so the whole timeline never finishes and thus does not repeat.